# Intermittent 419, 401, 403 during Laravel Echo and Laravel Ajax Authentication Failure

Tags: php, laravel-5

Laravel authentication failure - See answer below.

My Original question:

I am receiving - intermittently - a 419 error upon refreshing a Laravel 5.6 / Vue app. The error appears with the AJAX to /broadcasting/auth to get authentication from my channels.php code - as a result I do not connect to the channel, and some JS fails (as expected).

The same code works 95% of the time, and if I get the error I just refresh (sometime 3 or 4 times) and it will work.

The channels.php auth is wide open for both the public and presence channels I connect to.. meaning I just return TRUE with no checking.

I understand a 419 error has to do with the CSRF, but why would it work by refreshing? And what could happen to it that I could fix to prevent it.

I suspected a timeout, but it can be 30sec, or 15 minutes - time has no factor.

I am at a loss to post code, as it is the base code as shipped so here is my setup

```
WAMP on Windows with PHP 7.2
Laravel 5.6
Echo through Pusher (service)
```

tested from Google, Safari, Firefox, Canary (all browsers have same issue)

I am assuming Axios is used for ajax, but, again it is the internal app.js / NPM compilation so I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it deep in Google search.... You are welcome, I am also editing the question to reflect my real problem so it is more easily searchable.

BTW do a `php artisan config:cache`

Thank you chijipon @ [laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/many-time-401-unauthorized-on-ajax-requests)

> When making simultaneous XHR requests, session data may be lost due to
>   concurrent requests updating the session at the same time. This is a
>   known issue. One solution may be reducing the number of requests, or
>   use **session locking **. This allows to lock the session file when
>   used, hence forcing all requests to be executed one after the other.
>   This may slow down your app, but eliminate the potential errors.
>
> Laravel does not include session locking by default. Someone made a
>   [Laravel package](https://github.com/rairlie/laravel-locking-session) to add the feature.
>   https://github.com/rairlie/laravel-locking-session
>
> It seems to have worked for me.